# Cardinality of certain subsets in vector spaces over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Assume that you have an $n$-dimensional vector space over a finite field (therefore the number of elements in the vector space is finite.) and $F$ is a subset of this vector space which contains $m$ elements. Let's $A$ is a subset of this vector space when the intersection of $A+A$ and $F$ is empty.

The question is this: What is a non trivial lower bound for the cardinality of $A$?

Thank you.

Comment: Is $A+A=\{a+b\mid a,b\in A\}$?

Comment: I imagine this would depend a lot on $F$.  Is $F$ given?  Or are we supposed to find a good lower bound that works for any $F$ (of size $n$) (i.e. "adversary" gets to pick $F$)?

Comment: "Let's $A$ is a subset of this vector space when the intersection of $A + A$ and $F$ is empty." I can't parse that statement, can you clarify it?

Comment: May I suggest reword as "Let $A$ be a subset of this vector space s.t. the intersection of $A+A$ and $F$ is empty"?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Why doesn't $A=\emptyset$ always suffice? Shouldn't it make more sense to ask for a nontrivial *upper* bound instead?

Comment: @user115608 the way you wrote this is still not clear. Don't you want an **upper** bound for $A$? Or you want a lower bound for the *maximum size* of $A$. Note that $A$ is the empty set would certainly work as $A+A$ will not intersect any $F$.

Comment: I am _guessing_ OP wants this: For any given $F$, there is a max-sized $A$ with size $|A| = g(F)$.  What is the $min_F g(F)$?  OP did say "I want a good lower bound that works for every $F$" so I interpret the choice of $F$ to be adversarial.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your "A beautiful question ..." which could be said about many issues (moreover, "beauty" is a disputable isssue) into a more meaningful, **searchable** title.

Comment: Here is the same question on MathOverflow: [A beautiful problem in linear algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/q/330579). [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) offers a very reasonable advice about [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can give an example where $A$ must be empty. Suppose your vector space is $(\mathbb{F}_2)^n$ and $F$ is any $n$ element subset that includes $0^n$. Then for each $a \in A$ indeed any $a \in (\mathbb{F}_2)^n$ note that $a+a = 0^n$.

In fact something similar would hold if $\mathbb{F}_2$ were replaced by any finite field with characteristic 2.

So your question as asked, the lower bound is 0 and it is tight.

---

ETA: If you require every element in $F$ to be nonzero, then [for the case where vector space $X$ is $(\mathbb{F}_2)^n$ anyway] $A$ can be as large as $|X|/2$. Indeed, let $F$ be the set of vectors $u$ in $(\mathbb{F}_2)^n$ such that exactly one coordinate in $u$ is nonzero, and let $A$ be the set of vectors $y$ such that $y$ has an even number of coordinates nonzero. Then $|A| = |X|/2$ but $A+A = A$--indeed $A$ is a vector space--and $A$ does not intersect $F$.

A set $A$ can be no larger. Indeed, if $A$ is larger than $|X|/2$ then $A+A$ contains every nonzero element $u$ of $(\mathbb{F}_2)^n$. Indeed,  $u +A$ has cardinality $> |X|/2$, and therefore intersects $A$ itself. So let $a_1,a_2 \in A$ be such that $u+a_1 = a_2$. Then as $u$ is nonzero, it follows that $a_1 \not = a_2$, and $a_1+a_2 = u$ so $u \in A+A$.

So half the number of elements in the vector space $X$ is an upper bound. And for $X =$  $(\mathbb{F}_2)^n$ it is a tight upper bound.

Comment: Not sure if it was edited later, but the problem specifies that $F$ contains non-zero elements.

Comment: +1 IIRC the non-zero part was added later.  This was a good answer until the question changed.  Wish the OP had acknowledged the change.

Comment: @Ingix see my edits

Comment: @antkam see my edits. Thank you both

Comment: Very interesting proof that $|A| > |X|/2 \implies A+A = X$.  I did not expect that.  :)  But I interpret OP to want a lower bound for the max-sized $A$ which works for any $F$.